# Создать функцию map с учетом уже имеющейся функции forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, map

В задании необходимо создать функцию map с учетом уже имеющейся функции forEach.
Когда передается function (el) { return el * 2; } в функцию forEach каждый элемент умножается на 2, но сам forEach не возвращает каждый элемент умноженный на 2.
Не могу понять, где ошибка.

```html
function forEach(arr, func){
  for(let el of arr){
    func(el);
  }
}

function map(arr, func){
    let res;
    let result = [...arr];
    res = result.push(forEach(result, func));
    console.log(result);
}
map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function (el) { return el * 2; });
```

Comment: вы `func(el)` нигде не сохраняете

Comment: forEach ничего не возвращает, ну и да - func выполнится 5 раз и всё, куда результат то аккумулироваться будет

Comment: @PavelNazarian. Можете подсказать, как сделать так, чтобы forEach возвращал? Что откорректировать? Я вижу, что func выполняется 5 раз и все, в массив увеличенный элемент не перердается.

Comment: @Seva Sleva что на выходе должно быть, массив с вычисленными значениями или объединенный с вводными данными?

Comment: @PavelNazarian , на выходе должен быть новый массив с вычисленными значениями. Если массив [1,2,3,4], то на выходе должен быть массив [2,4,6,8]. Методы массивов, кроме .push, использовать нельзя.

Comment: @PavelNazarian , не успел посмотреть Ваш вариант решения, удалили код

Comment: @Seva Sleva потому что закрались сомнения  в задании. Одна из функций лишняя, по-моему ) Но раз по заданию две, то я пожалуй воздержусь

Comment: @PavelNazarian, а могли бы, все-таки, продублировать Ваше решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` делает копию массива, в которую помещает результат обработки каждого элемента исходного массива.

`forEach` занимается обработкой исходного массива, применяя переданную функцию к каждому элементу. Поэтому можно просто передать `forEach` функцию (callback), которая будет помещать результат действия функции, переданной в `map`, над каждым элементом исходного массива.

Таким образом, изначальный массив остается неизмененным, а `map` возвращает новый массив элементов, над каждым из которых была произведена операция переданной в `map` функцией (callback).

Здесь надо понимать, что массивы передаются в функции по ссылке. Поэтому, когда мы передаем пустой массив `result` в функцию-коллбэк `forEach`, то любые изменения с ним отражаются и здесь, внутри `map`. И наоборот, передавая `arr` в качестве аргумента в `forEach`, каждый элемент этого массива (будучи примитивными) передается в коллбэк по значению и на этот массив никак не отражается.

```js
function forEach(arr, func){
  for(let el of arr){
    func(el);
  }
}

function map(arr, func){
    const result = [];
    forEach(arr, el => {
        result.push(func(el));
    })
    return result;
}

let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
let mapped_array = map(array, el => el*2);

console.log('Initial array: ', array);
console.log('Mapped array: ', mapped_array);
```